# Keeping specific dependencies up to date while using package-lock.json and npm ci

Tags: git, npm, continuous-integration

I've been reading around, and from my understanding it's generally recommended to run `npm ci` to install required dependencies based on `package-lock.json`.

My team's workflow involves running `npm ci` (with other things) in our CI. We're also interested in getting `latest` on some specific dependencies in which we're expecting them have updates multiple times a day.

With that, I find myself needing to run `npm install` to get updates from said dependencies and keep my `package-lock.json` updated before pushing to the git repo.

Is there an automated/better way to work with this? Anything to add in our CI?